# Is Indus Valley Civilization off-topic at HSE?

Tags: discussion, support

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashupati_seal

One seal is said to represent the Pashupati form of Siva.

The eminent cryptographer Iravatam Mahadevan thinks Mahadeva and Neelakantha can be deciphered from the inscriptions.

The famous dancing girl statuette is said to be of Parvati.

https://www.news18.com/news/india/historian-who-said-dancing-girl-is-parvati-dates-sindoor-to-harappan-age-1327897.html

Comment: We need to see the exact question before we can decide if its off topic or not. For example, if one asks "Is science off-topic?" its not enough. One needs to produce the exact question on science so that one can decide. Certain questions about science are on topic but many are not. So one can't decide without seeing the exact question.

Comment: If "we have to see the question" it is on topic.  Now Machu Pichu we can rule out quite easily, but not Indus Valley.  It would be good if mods say "yea" or "nay" @rickross

Comment: Mods alone don't decide the scope, we also have our say in it. But  I don't think even Mods can decide in this case without seeing exactly what the question about IVC is.